# Using different D3 versions on same html page

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am try to construct treelist and treemap in single html page using d3.js.
My treelist and treemap are working fine on individual pages,but i want to combine those into single html page.

The problem i am facing is, for treelist i am using d3.js **version 3** and for treemap i am using d3.js **version 4**. So when i try to embedded them into my single page there are version conflicts(it just shows the treemap).

Please guide me how should i resolve the version conflicts.

Following is my d3.js code with Version 3(first col-md-4) and Version 4(col-md-8)

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="treelisttest" style="height:500px;">   </div>

        <script>

                    var id = 0;
                    d3.json("data.json", function (err, data) {

                        var tree = d3.layout.treelist()
                                 .childIndent(10)
                                 .nodeHeight(30);

                        var ul = d3.select("#treelisttest").append("ul").classed("treelist", "true");

                        function render(data, parent) {
                            var nodes = tree.nodes(data),
                                duration = 250;
                            function toggleChildren(d) {

                                if (d.children) {
                                    d._children = d.children;
                                    d.children = null;
                                } else if (d._children) {
                                    d.children = d._children;
                                    d._children = null;
                                }
                            }

                            var nodeEls = ul.selectAll("li.node").data(nodes, function (d) {
                                d.id = d.id || ++id;
                                return d.id;
                            });

                            var entered = nodeEls.enter().append("li").classed("node", true)
                                .style("top", parent.y + "px")
                                .style("opacity", 0)
                                .style("height", tree.nodeHeight() + "px")
                                .on("click", function (d) {
                                    toggleChildren(d);
                                    render(parent, d);
                                })
                                .on("mouseover", function (d) {
                                    d3.select(this).classed("selected", true);
                                })
                                .on("mouseout", function (d) {
                                    d3.selectAll(".selected").classed("selected", false);
                                });

                            entered.append("span").attr("class", function (d) {
                                var icon = d.children ? " glyphicon-chevron-down"
                                    : d._children ? "glyphicon-chevron-right" : "";
                                return "caret glyphicon " + icon;
                            });

                            entered.append("span").attr("class", function (d) {
                                var icon = d.children || d._children ? "glyphicon-folder-close"
                                    : "glyphicon-file";
                                return "glyphicon " + icon;
                            });

                            entered.append("span").attr("class", "filename")
                            .html(function (d) { return d.name.substring(0, 5) });

                            nodeEls.select("span.caret").attr("class", function (d) {
                                var icon = d.children ? " glyphicon-chevron-down"
                                    : d._children ? "glyphicon-chevron-right" : "";
                                return "caret glyphicon " + icon;
                            });

                            nodeEls.transition().duration(duration)
                                .style("top", function (d) { return (d.y - tree.nodeHeight()) + "px"; })
                                .style("left", function (d) { return d.x + "px"; })
                                .style("opacity", 1);
                            nodeEls.exit().remove();
                        }

                        render(data, data);

                    });
        </script>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div id="maptest">

            <script src="http://d3js.org/d4.v3.min.js"></script>


            <svg width="500" height="1000"></svg>

            <script src="d3.v4.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                var svg = d3.select("#maptest")
                       .append("svg")
                       .attr("width", "100%")
                       .attr("height", "50%")
                       .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
                           svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
                       }))
                       .append("g")



            var treemap = d3.treemap()
                .tile(d3.treemapResquarify)
                .size([1000, 1000])
                .round(true)
                .paddingInner(1);

            d3.json("data.json", function (error, data) {
                if (error) throw error;

            var root = d3.hierarchy(data)
                .sum(sumBySize)

                treemap(root);

                var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
                    .data(root.leaves())
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x0 + "," + d.y0 + ")"; });

                cell.append("rect")
                    .attr("id", function (d) { return d.data.id; })
                    .attr("width", function (d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
                    .attr("height", function (d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
                    .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.data.value); });

                cell.append("clipPath")
                    .attr("id", function (d) { return "clip-" + d.data.id; })
                    .append("use")
                    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return "#" + d.data.id; });

                cell.append("text")
                    .attr("dy", ".75em")
                    .text(function (d) { return d.data.name.substring(0, 1); })

                cell.append("title")
                    .text(function (d) { return d.data.id + " with name " + d.data.name });
            });


        function sumByCount(d) {
            return d.children ? 0 : 1;
        }

        function sumBySize(d) {
            return d.value;
        }

            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in chrome console?

Comment: no i am not getting error

Comment: It could be that your treemap is rendering in the same container as treelist. Do you have a codepen or something with the code?

Comment: nops i dont have codepen

Comment: i have binded the treemap and treelist to different id's.

Comment: Can you paste the code here at least so I and other can have a look?

Comment: You cannot use both versions of d3.js in the same HTML page. It will make ambiguity while rendering the SVG elements.Because of the same namespace in both the version

Comment: sure.. give  me a moment

Comment: @Arvind Cheekkallur... is there any way where we can club both version's in same page

Comment: @Bob. Did you try to implement tree map and tree list in d3.v4? Clubbing of both versions is hard it seems

Comment: oh.. I tried to convert my treelist using version 4 but didn't get any positives from it.

Comment: Can you also upload your data somewhere, or at least a sample?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can download the version 3 of the script locally and change the last line from

```
this.d3 = d3;
```

to

```
this.d3v3 = d3;
```

So you can use d3 version 4 calling d3, and the version 3 of the library calling d3v3

Comment: :) simple and effective

Comment: Just needed a quick fix before the upgrade. Can't thank you enough for this!!

Comment: Can you tell where is the last line: this.d3 = d3; ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this solution? I can't seem to find the line this.d3 =d3.

Answer (score 8):

*(I don't know why you are trying to do this, or if this is really necessary. Have in mind that **I'm just answering your question**, that is, how to use D3 v3 and v4 in the same page, without analysing your objectives or if this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))*.

As you must know by now, you cannot just reference both versions in the HTML:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Because, obviously, that will cause a conflict when you use `d3` to call the methods.

Thus, the solution is *downloading* one of the two versions and changing the source code.

In this solution, I'll change the source code of the v4.x version (minified) and use the regular reference to the v3. You can do the other way around (as Daniela did in [her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44175745/5768908)), but the steps are not the same.

In D3 v4.x (minified), you see this at the beginning:

```
// https://d3js.org Version 4.9.1. Copyright 2017 Mike Bostock.
(function(t, n) {
    "object" == typeof exports && "undefined" != typeof module ?
        n(exports) : "function" == typeof define && define.amd ?
        define(["exports"], n) : n(t.d3 = t.d3 || {})
}) etc...
```

What I'm gonna do is changing that `t.d3` to `t.d3v4` (or any other name you want).

After that, you can use `d3` to call your D3 v3 functions and `d3v4` (not `d3`) to call your D3 v4 functions.

Like in this example:

```
var scalev3 = d3.scale.linear()
    //note:    ^----- use `d3` for D3 v3 functions
    .range([0, 5000])

var scalev4 = d3v4.scaleLinear()
    //note:     ^----- use `d3v4` for D3 v4 functions
    .range([0, 200]);

console.log(scalev3(0.4))//logs 2000, as expected.
console.log(scalev4(0.4))//logs 80, as expected.
```

Here is the plunker with that code: https://plnkr.co/edit/h174Gcc3YSCJGpNljCOh?p=preview

Comment: this is better solution as accepted answer is not working with angular

Answer (score 0):

I Use RequireJS to resolve this issue

- treelist d3 **Version : 3**

  ```
       require( ["js/common/d3.v3.min"], function(d3) {
          // tree list code here
         });
  ```
- treemap d3 **Version : 4**

  ```
  require( ["js/common/d3.v4.min"], function(d3) {       
  // treemap code here
  ```

  }

Note : You need to import require.js file : download it from here

http://requirejs.org/docs/1.0/docs/download.html

put the import statement at the end of body tag i.e.

< body>

// code 
....

< /body >